# Excise EOF character from AWK processing

Tags: awk

Watch this:

`echo one two three | awk 'BEGIN {RS=" "; FS=""} {print NF}'`

```
3
3
6
```

That last count is suspicious.  Let's have a look at the last field of each record:

`echo one two three | awk 'BEGIN {RS=" "; FS=""} {print $NF}'`

```
e
o
e
```

I will take a wild guess and assume AWK is picking up some sort of EOF character after the last field of the last record.

How do I tell AWK to ignore such extraneous character?

Comment: Exlicitly remove it? `sub("\n", "")`

Comment: or not send it: `echo -n one two three | awk 'BEGIN {RS=" "; FS=""} {print NF}'`

Comment: Cheeky & helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input stream includes a trailing `\n`.

By default `awk` will treat that trailing `\n` as the record separator (as opposed to part of the data).

In your code you've redefined `awk's` record separator as a space, thus leaving the `\n` to be treated as part of the input data.

If your version of `awk` supports multiple record separators you could define a dual record separator of space and `\n`, eg:

```
$ echo one two three | awk 'BEGIN {RS="[ \n]"; FS=""} {print NF}'
3
3
5
```

Or, as mentioned in the comment, you could explicitly remove the `\n`, eg:

```
$ echo one two three | awk 'BEGIN {RS=" "; FS=""} {sub(/\n/,"");print NF}'
3
3
5
```

Alternatively you could strip the `\n` before calling `awk`, eg:

```
$ echo one two three | tr -d '\n' | awk 'BEGIN {RS=" "; FS=""} {print NF}'
3
3
5
```

Or you could even skip the generation of the `\n` in the first place, eg:

```
$ printf "one two three" | awk 'BEGIN {RS=" "; FS=""} {print NF}'
3
3
5
```